# Images not scaling when re positioning window in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The issue is pretty easy to explain but even looking up tutorials the answer doesn't seem so clear cut for me. When I resize the window I was hoping the button would re postion itself based on the window

[Here you can see the image is not repositioning based on the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gLKD.gif)

```
<MainMenu>
    name: 'Gotta catch em all'
    #Createing canvas
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'backgroundImagees.jpeg'
    RelativeLayout:

        Button:
            background_normal: 'bitterling.png'
            size_hint:2,2
            #pos_hint:{"left":1,"top":7.5}
            pos_hint:{"x":.1,"y":5.8}
```

and here is the other file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle,Color
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','resizable',True)

kivy.require('1.11.1')

class MainMenu(Widget):
    pass

class AnimalCrossingApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MainMenu()

AnimalCrossingApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does..
Your problem is that the `hint` properties of a widget are used from its parent to position this widget inside the parent, but only if the parent is a `Layout`.
In your case, it does position the `Button` inside the `RelativeLayout` but the `RelativeLayout` is not handled by its parent (which is just a `Widget`, not a `Layout`), and as a consequence it goes to the bottom left.

A simple solution is to use a `FloatLayout`:

`class MainMenu(FloatLayout):`

and position every child with hints..